# Scrapy Start URL using date range

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, scrapy, range

I am trying to create a spider to crawl multiple pages by using a date range .

The below code works fine but I am hoping to create a loop so I can just input 2 dates and crawl every date in between the 2 instead of having to enter every date manually. I would like to crawl every date since 2018-01-01. The url is the exact same except for the date.

```
'''
class Example(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com.au']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com.au/example2/2020-06-18'
'''
```

I am trying the below but am getting error:

raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)

ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

```
'''
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from datetime import timedelta, date



class example(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com.au']
    
    def daterange(start_date, end_date):
        for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
            yield start_date + timedelta(n)

    start_date = date(2020, 6, 26)
    end_date = date(2020, 7, 2)
    start_urls = 'https://www.example.com.au/example2/'
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        print(single_date.strftime(start_urls+"%Y-%m-%d"))
    


    rules = (
    

     Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//td[@class='example__example']/a"), 
     callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timedelta and date.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2020, 6, 18)
end_date = date(2020, 7, 2)
start_urls = []
start_url='https://www.example.com.au/example2/'
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    start_urls.append(single_date.strftime(start_url+"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Girija! Unfortunately the code isn't working, I am getting these errors. 
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Comment: Can you please provide the snippet of code where you are using start_urls or at what point you are getting this error.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the code i am trying.

Comment: I think start_urls is a list in your code. I have modified the answer. Please let me know if you getting any issues.